# spark and mongo db connector parameterize aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to create a dataframe (in databricks) from a mongo collection , I need to pick 90 days worth of  data from the collection. when I hard code the date it works fine but when  I try to parametrize I get an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid pipeline option` ,

need to understand how I can pass parameters to this pipeline query
`pipeline = "{'$match': {'timestamp':{$gte: ISODate(DATE_VARIABLE)}}}`

the code  is like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

pipeline = "{'$match': {'timestamp':{$gte: ISODate('2021-10-01')}}}" # need to parameterize this date here 
df = (spark.read
           .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") 
           .option("uri", connectionString)
           .option("database", 'my database')
           .option("collection", 'my collection')
           .option("pipeline", pipeline)
           .load())
```

Answer (score 0):

figured a way out

need to append '' with the param always , only then it  will work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

date_variable ="'2020-01-01'"

pipeline = "{'$match': {'timestamp':{$gte: ISODate(%s)}}}"  % date_variable
df = (spark.read
           .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") 
           .option("uri", connectionString)
           .option("database", 'my database')
           .option("collection", 'my collection')
           .option("pipeline", pipeline)
           .load())
```